# document.addEventListener() in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, onload, addeventlistener

I am newbie to phonegap developemnt.

I have started with Phonegap tutorial and develop some UI using HTML5 and jqueryMobile.

Now i want to create database using Phonegap, i came across some tutorial for it also.

i saw a method called `document.addEventListener()` with 3 parameters from where `onDeviceReady()` function is called.

In some tutorial the `document.addEventListener()` was called in `onLoad()` method and in some it is just outside the onLoad().

Now my Question is when the `document.addEventListener()` is called...and where is the better way to call this menthod in `onLoad()` or outside the `onLoad()`..?

Also the third parameter of document.addEventListener() is false, what that parameter do?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It depends on where you need it. You can call it everywhere in the script. Ask google for the third parameter.

Comment: Third parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener